# Database Diagram folder in Azure SQL Edge not available?

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql, apple-m1, azure-sql-edge

**Background**

I am trying to learn `Transact-SQL` on my `M1 MacBook Pro` laptop. Unfortunately `Sequel Server Management Studio` is not available for Macs, so I am running `Azure SQL Edge` through `Docker`.

I tried to run `Azure Data Studio` but alas it seems to only run for `Intel based Macs` and not for `ARM` based laptops.

**Missing Folder**

I am trying to **establish a relationship** between two tables in `Azure SQL Edge` but unfortunately, it requires for me to right click on the `Database Diagram folder` which I cannot find. Can somebody help me finding this folder?

Comment: _"I am trying to establish a relationship between two tables in Azure SQL Edge"_ - can't you do it manually (y'know, by typing `ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Foo_Bar FOREIGN KEY...` ?)

Comment: Database Diagrams is a feature of SSMS and SSDT, [but not ADS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53293349/159145). Looks like you'll need to fire-up a Windows VM.