Drawing Relationships In Entity Relationship Diagram
I used Azure to create a database. I used Azure Data Studio and https://github.com/R0tenur/visualization to create the following Entity Relationship Diagram / Relational Model (?). Are the relationships drawn correctly or reversed? Is it correct to read one relationship as "Between one and one course has between one and many outcomes."?


Explanation of ER model to functional dependencies solution

The relationships seem indeed inverted: this diagram tells that:

an outcome shall have one or many courses
each course must have one outcome

The cardinality symbol on the side of the outcomes tells how many outcomes can be related to one element of the opposite side, and vice-versa. The element closest to a table can be a bar (one) or a trident (many). The element next to it tells about the participation, which is either a bar (mandatory) or a circle (optional).
The foreign keys in your tables confirm that the other relationships are also inverted.
Here a link with more explanations on the crow's foot ERD notation and of course wikipedia.

Thank you, @Christophe. I noted this issue in comments to the replies of Samuele Furnari and Diego Alberto Zapata Häntsch at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293349/azure-data-studio-schema-diagram.

@TomLever thank you for enriching stackoverflow with your findings, and the extra effort to find the issue in the source repository. This will help others in the same situation. It's unfortunate  that the tool other doesn't have interest in correcting it. However his comment points to the core of the logic. A first step could be to invert the relationships generated in that function (e.g. "}|--||" and "||--o{ instead of "||--|{" and "|o--|{. A second step would be to add a case to distinguish  nullable and unique for "||--o|" since both are not mutually exclusive. Can you try ?

@TomLever and if it works, feel free to propose the PR for the common good ;-)

Christophe, thank you for your affirmation and suggestions, which are really refreshing. Inspired by your suggestions, I created pull request https://github.com/R0tenur/visualization/pull/153, including detailed instructions for using the extension. Would you please review my pull request, especially my changes in my first commit "Corrected inverted relationships" to backend/src/services/builder.service.ts?

@TomLever That's really great!  And thank you for quoting me ;-) The new diagram generated is correct so PR dramatically improves the tool.  Looking into PR code,  I have the impression that the two 1st symbols are inverted for some returns. I have understood that the package uses mermaid for the rendering,  and I don't know if mermaid is tolerant on that or not (see doc here, column "Value(left)"): https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/entityRelationshipDiagram.html#relationship-syntax ).  To be sure you should do also a quick test with tome dummy tables to cover all the cases it's supposed to cover.

@TomLever but anyhow, thanks for the improvement for the community :-)

If I change if (column.nullable) { return "|}--o|"; } to if (column.nullable) { return "}|--o|"; }, I receive the following error in Azure Data Studio: "Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service worker: InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state.."

I can change return "|{--||"; to return "}|--||";. You seem to recommend this change.

@TomLever interesting.  Let's try. Maybe it's not a pure mermaid after all.
